# Counter-intuitive: Mean of absolute value of normalized Gaussian Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matlab

Here's a simple matlab code:

```
    n = 10; % Any natural number  
    X = randn(n,1);
    X = X/norm(X);
    mean(abs(X))
```

This always comes out to be empirically around $$\frac{1}{1.25 \sqrt{n}} $$ But I intuitively feel that it should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Because the entries are independent and the norm is one. Please explain how the 1.25 factor comes. Also, this is independent of the variance of the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This multiplicative factor is not exactly $\dfrac1{1.25}=0.8$, even taking its expected value rather than a particular simulation

- for small $n$, the factor is larger as the norm is substantially affected by the particular sample values: for example with $n=1$ it is $1$ as the norm has exactly the same magnitude as the original data, while for $n=2$ its expected value is (empirically) closer to $0.9$
- for large $n$ the expected factor approaches $\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi} \approx 0.79788$ when $n$ increases, as the mean of the absolute value of a standard normal random variable (sometimes called the [*half-normal distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution))

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you explain the intuition behind it not being $1/\sqrt(n)$ even though the vector is normalized, and entries independent? Maybe I am missing something basic here. A little help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: @Enayat If your `norm(X)` were always exactly $\sqrt{n}$ (and it will usually be close to this for large $n$) then you would be looking at the expected value of $\frac{|X_i|}{\sqrt{n}}$.  Since the expected value of $|X_i|$ is $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$, this gives something close to $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for large $n$, rather than just $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$